# Open JDK 14 for Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, openjdk, jdk

I have read tons but can't find the answer to this.

I want to install openjdk14 on ubuntu 18.04.

I do not want oraclejdk14. I do not want openjdk11.

Countless articles claim you can just apt install it, yet ubuntu repository says otherwise as does my server.

Tutorials keep trying to have me install oraclejdk14.

What are instructions for openjdk14?

Comment: According to http://packages.ubuntu.com, the `openjdk-14-jdk` package is available for Ubuntu 20.04 and 20.10, not for 18.04.

Comment: Yup tutorials across the internet are wrong about 18.04,

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to find this so hopefully this helps others.

```
wget https://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk14/ri/openjdk-14+36_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
tar xvfz openjdk-14+36_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
mv ./jdk-14/ /usr/lib/jvm/
update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14/bin/javac" 1081
update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14/bin/java" 1081
update-alternatives --set "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14/bin/javac"
update-alternatives --set "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14/bin/java"
update-alternatives --config java
```